# Parking brake sensor?

Tags: ford, fiesta, parking-brake

I have a '16 Fiesta ST 6-speed.  Particularly in cold weather before the car has warmed up, I'll release the parking brake and start driving, but the brake light will come back on at the slightest touch to the brake handle.

Applying a tiny bit of pressure to the handle turns the light (and warning off) but until the car has warmed a bit a few bumps can nudge the handle just a bit and activate the light and chime.

Is this something I can adjust myself, or do I need to take it in to have it adjusted/fixed/whatever?  (I don't think this is a case of low brake fluid etc, since I can with almost no effort "fix" it via the handle...)

Comment: Have you checked the handbrake cable - is it sticking? That could cause this type of priblem.

Comment: I'm a noob w/r/t car troubleshooting - how would I check this?